# Linear equations with modulus

Tags: linear-algebra

For a given prime $P$ and given coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $V$, $W$, I need to determine $x$ and $y$ from this system:

$ax \mod P + by \mod P = V$

$cx \mod P + dy \mod P = W$

Note that the values $V$ and $W$ can be larger than $P$.

Comment: Do you mean $ax+ by \equiv  V (\mathrm{mod}  P)$ ?

Comment: there is an underlying skill: if I give you a number $n$ that is not divisible by $p,$ do you know how to find a number $t$ so that $tn \equiv 1 \pmod p \; ? \; \; $

Comment: @mouthetics i believe that is what is meant, but also with the constraint that $V,W$ can be greater than $P$ (although this wouldn't change the answer).

Comment: Does $\ P\nmid ad-bc?\ $

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the trivial cases we assume that $p\nmid abcd$.

The determinant of the system is $\Delta= ad - bc$.

$$\Delta_x = vd-wb \text{ and }\Delta_y = aw - cv.$$

If $p\nmid \Delta$ then $$x\equiv \Delta^{-1}\Delta_x \, (\mathrm{mod } p) \text{ and } y\equiv \Delta^{-1} \Delta_y\, (\mathrm{mod } p)$$

If $p\mid \Delta$ then for the system to be compatible you must have  $$\begin{cases}bw-dv\equiv 0\; (\mathrm{mod } p) \\ aw -cv \equiv 0\; (\mathrm{mod } p)\end{cases}$$
But by assumption this is same as $$ w\equiv db^{-1} v \; (\mathrm{mod } p)$$
And the system becomes equivalent to one equation $$ ax+by\equiv v \;(\mathrm{mod } p),$$
Which has as solution the couples $(x,-ab^{-1}x+vb^{-1})$.